# C++ Web Toolkit

Tags: c++, winapi

Кто работал с WT на C++ под Windows она может рендерить HTML в приложении winapi?

Comment: Вряд ли. Задача веб-фреймворка - выдать готовый hmtl (в виде текста). А его рендерингом (отрисовкой) должен заниматься браузер.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov я так понимаю мне нужно искать движок браузера?